# jQuery Slide Toggle on next class not next sibling

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle

I have data being pulled out from a database in a while loop. One item consists of a mini nav, the database item, hidden divs that relate to the menu. When you click on an item in this menu, I want a div to slide out from beneath the database item.

So

```
while($row = mnysql_fetch_array($q)){
   <li>
    row data
    hidden divs
   </li>
   menu
}

<script>
slidetoggle script here
</script>
```

My problem is that with my jquery function. It only selects the siblings. I need the menu out of the li. So how do I select the a hidden div from the list item above the menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Slide toggle for buttons
    $('.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
  });
 });

                    `
<ul class="comment-links">
<li id="com-link">
    <a href="#" title="View Comments" class="view-comments toggle-trigger">View Comments</a>
    <div class="comments toggle">
        <p>bla bla</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="add-com-btn">
    <a href="#" title="Add a comment" class="add-comment-btn toggle-trigger">Add a comment</a>
    <div class="add-comment-form toggle">
        add comment form
    </div><!--end add comment form-->
</li>
<li id="down-btn">
    <a href="uploads/Test document.pdf" title="Download Document" target="_blank" class="dwnld-doc-btn-2">Download Document</a>
</li>
```

Comment: where is the `toggle-trigger` element

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: the generated html is also too long to include. Here is the question again: I multiple divs on a page with the class "toggle". I need the slidetoggle() to affect these divs. The class .toggle-trigger will be not be related to the toggle class. At the moment, the code I have only works on the next sibling class. So toggle and toggle-trigger has to be siblings. That is my restriction.

Comment: you need to provide a sample of generated html along with the `li` - one `li` element will do

Comment: Are the `divs` only hidden visually?  

If they are in the generated code you could consider using a query selector for the nested divs if there is something unique or predictable about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give them a shared parent, it is better to use pure javascript like this:

try using the `find` method it searches the child nodes only. for each li, we can find the .toggle-trigger and .toggle elements within that li and add seperate events for each one

```
$('li').each(function(){
  var node = this;
  node.find('.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
    $(node).find('.toggle');
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think we are misunderstanding each other. I need the .toggle outside the li and ul. The toggle class needs to be applied to elememts away from the menu (ul)

Comment: if they can't be underneath a unique parent, you will have to give them auto-generated id's

Answer (score 0):

If you can't give the related items a shared parent, you will have to give them unique ids.

each trigger is associated with a hidden div using an id generated in php `$row.id` the id is stored using a custom attribute `data-id`. jquery then uses this id to select the correct element. e.g. `toggle-3`

```
<?php while($row = mnysql_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
            <div class=".toggle" id="toggle-<?php $row.id?>">
<?php }
      while($row = mnysql_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
            <div class=".toggle-trigger" data-id="<?php $row.id?>">
<?php } ?>
```

In Javascript

```
$('.toggle-trigger').click(function(){
    var toggleId= 'togle-' + this.get('data-id');
    $('#'+ toggleId).slideToggle()
  });
```